# How to rebase local branch onto remote master

Tags: git, clone, git-rebase

I have a cloned project from a master branch from remote repository `remote_repo`. I created a new branch and I committed to that branch. Other programmers pushed to the master branch in the `remote_repo`.

I now need to rebase my local branch `RB` onto `remote_repo`'s `master` branch.

How to do this? What commands to type to a terminal?

Answer (score 1713):

First fetch the new master from the upstream repository, then rebase your work branch on that:

```
git fetch origin            # Updates origin/master
git rebase origin/master    # Rebases current branch onto origin/master
```

**Update**: Please see [Paul Draper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18442755/91757) for a more concise way to do the same - recent Git versions provide a simpler way to do the equivalent of the above two commands.

Comment: this is the only answer that actually does what was asked

Comment: @kayaker243 No, it is the same as Paul Drapers answer but in long form, I think.

Comment: @erik Note that Paul Draper wrote his answer about half a year after kayaker243's comment (and almost two years after this answer).

Comment: I get the following: `Your branch and 'origin/b1' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 2 different commits each, respectively.` Seems like another `git pull` is needed. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dror No, there's no `git pull` needed. It means that since the last time you fetched from the `origin` repository, you did three commits. You later fetched again and git noticed that apparently other people did two commits since you last fetched. So now you can either rebase your branch on top of `origin`'s branch (that's what this question is about and what my answer describes), or you can merge your local branch and the one from `origin` using `git merge`.

Comment: I started a follow up question here: http://superuser.com/questions/667146/rebasing-a-branch-which-is-public

Comment: -  git rebase master   # will do the same job as the second command?
-  after the two commands, my local master and RB has the same version of code, right?  But i want master to be intact as remote master (without any RB commits)

Comment: @RGC No, `git rebase master` will not do the same job as the second command (`git rebase origin/master`) since `master` and `origin/master` may well point to different commits (especially given that the first command was `git fetch origin`, which may modify `origin/master`).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I by chance just did `git rebase origin` and not `git rebase origin/master`. What will happen?

Comment: Is the origin here refered to an upstream repo or a fork?

Comment: @reversiblean `origin` refers to any other Git repository.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe say for example I have upstream (read-only) and origin (fork). Should I rebase over `upstream` or the `origin`?

Comment: My problem is to later push my rebased feature-branch to remote. I get endless errors which I fail to resolve. I usually give up, - delete the feature branch on the remote repo, then push it again from my local. That's not very nice. Could you please elaborate just a little more on how to finalize the rebase by pushing the feature-branch to remote?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I understand that `origin` = `remote_repo` as if previously he could have done `git remote add origin https://github.com/whoever/remote_repo.git`?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I have the same issue. Are both of these commands run on the local branch or one on local master and the other on local branch?

Comment: @Suleka_28 Both commands are run while having the same branch checked out: the branch which you want to rebase onto the remote `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Was really helpful to me and helped me to easily resolve my conflicts

Comment: For most modern repos you'll find you'll need to swap `master` for `main`.

Comment: Please add to your answer which branch you are (or have just checked out) when you issue these commands.

Answer (score 1329):

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Comment: (Equivalent to Frerich's answer)

Comment: isn't this slightly different than Frerich's answer, in that this will commit changes from origin master onto local master, whereas Frerich's answer leaves local master untouched? (pull vs. fetch)

Comment: No, in Frerich's answer, the rebase modifies the local master. A pull --rebase is the same thing as a fetch followed by a rebase

Comment: FYI you can do interactive rebases with `git pull --rebase=interactive origin master`

Comment: @adhominem - I checked the [git-pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), and I can't see anything that supports the claim that the local master is modified. If I'm on a branch named `dev` and run `git pull --rebase origin master`, only branch `dev` is going to be modified, not `master`. The `--rebase` flag documentation states that it attempts to `rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching` and nothing about modifying local tracking branches.

Comment: @studro I was assuming you were calling pull --rebase while on the local master. Otherwise, I would have been wrong.

Comment: Ahh right - that make sense. Thanks. I was just a little confused as I think the original question implies that they were on a local branch (`RB` I think they called it?) other than `master`.

Comment: Is there a way to do an interactive rebase using this one liner?

Comment: My problem is to later push my rebased feature-branch to remote. I get endless errors that I can't resolve. I usually give up - delete the remote branch and push it again from my local, but that's not very nice. Can you please elaborate just a little more on how to finalize the rebase by pushing it to remote?

Comment: I got `invalid upstream 'origin/master'` when I tried Frerich's answer, but this answer works. I think it was because I only cloned a single branch.

Comment: And if you want to update the master branch then, without checking out to it, use:

```git fetch origin master:master```

Comment: When I used the proposed 1 liner command from @PaulDraper I got: `Your branch and 'origin/XXX' have diverged, and have 17 and 5 different commits each, respectively. (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)` What does this mean exactly? Should I do a git pull?

Comment: I prefer this one because `git fetch origin` brings all remote branches, even incomplete ones, while I only need a specific branch. And a one-line is preferred

Comment: Please add to your answer which branch you are on (or have checked out) when you issue this command.

Answer (score 378):

After committing changes to your branch, checkout `master` and pull it to get its latest changes from the repo:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Then checkout your branch and rebase your changes on `master`:

```
git checkout RB
git rebase master
```

...or last two commands in one line:

```
git rebase master RB
```

When trying to push back to `origin/RB`, you'll probably get an error; if you're the only one working on `RB`, you can force push:

```
git push --force origin RB
```

...or as follows if you have git configured appropriately:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: when trying to push back to origin/RB, you'll probably get an error. If youre the only one working on RB, you can git push --force origin RB.    source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase

Comment: Ah.... I have exactly this. my "RB" is rebased correctly, but I get endless errors when trying to push it after the rebase. Aside from push --force origin RB - is there a "nicer" (non forced) way to do it? I just try to understand gits perception here - and fail.

Comment: @MottiShneor No, there is no nice way. If someone else pushes to the branch in the mean time, their changes will be lost! If you want to be nice to the git commit history, you should rather merge master into your branch, which is safe (you can do `git push` without `-f`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This has helped me a lot. A lot.

Comment: `git push --force-with-lease` is a safer way to push changes after a rebase. It basically checks if another member of your team has made a commit before pushing your changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force

Answer (score 171):

**Note:** If you already have experience with `rebase` then use the one liner below for a fast rebase option.

***The one-liner solution:***

This assumes you are on your working branch and you are the only person working on it.

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/master
```

Resolve any conflicts, test your code, commit and push new changes to the remote branch.

***The longer solution for those new to `rebase`:***

**Step 1:** This assumes that there are no commits or changes to be made on YourBranch at this point.

First we checkout YourBranch:

```
git checkout YourBranch
git pull --rebase
```

**What happened?** We just pulled all changes made by other developers working on YourBranch and rebased your changes on top of this rebased version.

**Step 2:** Resolve any conflicts brought up by the rebase.

**Step 3:** Rebase your local master on the remote master:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
```

**What happened?** We just pulled all the latest changes from the remote master and rebased our local master on the remote master. I always keep the remote master clean and release ready! I also prefer to work on master or other branches locally. I recommend this approach until you become comfortable with git changes and commits.

Note: Step 3 is not needed if you are not maintaining local master, in which case you can do a `fetch` and `rebase remote master` directly on your local branch, as in the single-step solution above.

**Step 4:** Resolve any conflicts brought up by the rebase.

**Step 5:** Rebase your (rebased) local YourBranch branch on the (rebased) local master:

```
git checkout YourBranch
git rebase master
```

**What happened?** We just rebased our local YourBranch on the local master branch, both of which we had previously rebased on the remote versions.

**Step 6:** Resolve any conflicts, if any. Use `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase after adding the resolved conflicts. At any time you can use `git rebase --abort` to abort the rebase.

**Step 7:**

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

**What happened?** We just pushed our changes to the remote YourBranch. `--force-with-lease` will determine whether there are any incoming changes for YourBranch from other developers while you rebasing. If there are such changes, git will fetch them to update your local YourBranch before pushing to the remote. This is more advisable than a plain `force push`, which will not fetch incoming changes from the remote.

**Yahoooo...! You have successfully done a rebase!**

You might also consider using:

```
git checkout master
git merge YourBranch
```

**When and Why?** This merges YourBranch into master if you and your co-developers are finished making changes to YourBranch. This makes YourBranch up-to-date with master when you want to work on this branch later.

```
                            ~:   (๑ơ ₃ ơ)♥ rebase   :~
```

Comment: What is this for: "Pulls all the latest changes from master and rebases master on latest master.".  Rebase master on master?  Dont you just need to pull the latest master?

Comment: @JohnLittle Thanks for pointing out. I mean `Pulls latest changes from remote master to local master. I always prefer keeping remote master clean and release ready always!`. I will update my description.

Comment: The `git push --force-with-lease ` is the tricky bit and what nobody talks about when rebasing as you'll get a `your branch is X ahead and Y behind origin` which if you try to pull and push again will make a huge mess of things.

Comment: Thank you so much for the `step 7`, this always confused me in rebasing since you need to merge anyway in the end and the initial question is always "should i merge or rebase"! Also the push with `--force-with-lease`  top stuff.

Comment: `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` or `git pull --rebase origin master` ?

Comment: @Jono `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` are two separate commands; where `git fetch` retrieves latest changes from master without merging and `git rebase origin/master` is to perform the actual rebase on top of latest master. Where as `git pull --rebase origin master` is combination of both these commands. I would suggest to use separate commands which gives a bit of more control especially when you're new to rebasing. But you can opt for other one for convenience.

Answer (score 44):

Step 1:

```
git fetch origin
```

Step 2:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Step 3:(Fix if any conflicts)

```
git add .
```

Step 4:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Step 5:

```
git push --force
```

Comment: No explanation as to which branch to start on. Not a good answer.

Comment: Please don't do this if you don't know exactly what is implies. Force pushing is not a good idea.

Comment: !!! please don't do `git push --force` can be very very dangerous. https://www.datree.io/resources/git-push-force

Comment: Most of the answers including the highest rated one is force pushing. If you will not force push you will not have the history lined up properly over master or whatever the branch you are rebasing on.

Comment: Should've been `git fetch origin master`

Comment: by the way, "git push --force" is a "must" otherwise if you use simple "git push" you'll have dublicated commits

Answer (score 30):

**1.Update Master first...**

```sh
git checkout [master branch]
git pull [master branch]
```

**2.Now rebase source-branch with master branch**

```sh
git checkout [source branch]
git rebase [master branch]
git pull [source branch] (remote/source branch)
git push [source branch]
```

**IF source branch does not yet exist on remote then do:**

```sh
git push -u origin [source branch]
```

**"et voila..."**

Comment: I like the step-by-step nature of this answer. It helps break down what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 8):

`git fetch origin master:master` pulls the latest version of master without needing to check it out.

So all you need is:

`git fetch origin master:master && git rebase master`

Comment: Doesn't `git fetch` update master without needing to check it out too? Except that `git fetch` doesn't `git merge` the updates right? So if we checkout `master` it won't have the latest updates. So isn't it shorter to do while on feature branch, `git fetch` then `git rebase origin/master`? We can't do `git rebase master` because that will try to rebase from `master` in workspace, we need `origin/master` to get from the unmerged but sitting in local.

Answer (score 6):

If the current branch has a lot of commits and they are needed to be squashed, fixed, and rewritten before rebasing, then interactive rebase is the correct answer. When software engineers say "rebase on top of master", what they usually mean is "do interactive rebase on top of origin/master and make sure it looks great and unnecessary commits are squashed, and commit messages are corrected".

First, check
`git status` and make sure to start in feature branch.

If not in feature brach, try `git checkout feature`
Then

```
git fetch origin
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Rarely, a commit history is ready to be rebased as is when rebase on top of master is requested. In most cases, the existing commits are first revised using the interactive rebase.

Answer (score 2):

**simple solution:**

`git checkout master && git pull`

`git checkout branch`

`git rebase master` -> resolve conflicts if any

`git add .`

`git rebase --continue`

`git push --force-with-lease origin branch`