# Git: Are you able to update branches after the master is changed?

Tags: git, github

Sorry about the n00b-ish questions here, but I'm not fully understanding how Git works apparently.

I have a project. I currently have three branches: `Master`, `A`, and `B`. `Master` is meant to have the newest version of the project that is released. Branches `A` and `B` were created upon the first release of the project. `A` is used to fix bugs in the current version while `B` is used to create new content for the project. I have made bug fixes using branch `A` and pushed them to `Master` (so `Master` now has the most recent, released version as desired).

The problem is, Branch `B` cannot see those fixes and so I am working with outdated code. Is there a way for me to "update" Branch `B` with the fixes from `A` without going in and copy/pasting all the code that was update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rebase local branch with remote master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master)

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the changes from `Master` into `B`:

```
git checkout B
git merge Master
```

If there are any merge conflicts, you will need to resolve them at this point and then commit the changes into `B`.