# git: Updating my fork and rebase

Tags: git, github, rebase

This is the situation:

```
repo    upstream     upstreamfork      myfork_from_upstreamfork
branch   master         testing             mybranch
           |
           |
           |-------------->|
                           |------------------->|
                           |
                           |
```

`upstreamfork` has new commits. I need to update `mybranch` from `myfork_from_upstreamfork` with the latest commits from `upstreamfork/testing`

I tried `git rebase upstreamfork/testing` from `mybranch`, but I get

> Current branch mybranch is up to date.

How do I correctly update my branch?

I am starting fresh on this project. Eventually I will issue PRs for `upstreamfork` - which may well be integrated into `upstream` at some point - so I don't want to mess up :shiver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rebase local branch with remote master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master)

Answer (score 0):

This question has the answer:
[How to rebase local branch with remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master)

needed to first fetch `testing` from `upstreamfork`. After that, `git rebase upstreamfork/testing` worked just fine