# Pull master being on another branch in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pull

When I'm on my branch I want to make `pull` from the `master` to get the latest version of code, then I rebase my branch onto `master` and after I push my branch to the server and create a pull request.

Today I do all of this the next way:

- I'm on `my_branch`, I switch to `master` branch
- After switch, being on `master`, I either execute `git pull` or in Intellij use the graphic interface `VCS->git->pull`
- I go back to `my_branch` and perform the rebase
- After rebase I make a `git push -f`

How could I avoid switching from `my_branch` to `master` and back in Intellij? Is there a way to pull the `master` to `master` being on another branch?

Comment: your local master is always like remote master? If that is the case, you can set up your feature branch to track remote master instead of local and then you could fetch/rebase (or pull --rebase) without having to switch to local master to do pull.

Comment: yes, `master` is a common branch for everybody and we create new branches and merge back to it. Nobody writes on master (except hot fixes that are quite rare)

Comment: well....no need to keep a local master... actually, you can keep it... but your feature branches (or whatever) can be started not from local master but from remote master. Then you won't need to switch to local master in order to rebase your feature on top of it, as I explained on my previous comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the master branch you talked about is on a remote called upstream, you can run the next 2 commands before pushing your code:

`git fetch
git rebase upstream/master`

If you didn't set any remotes, the default remote name is origin and in that case the commands are:

`git fetch
git rebase origin/master`

git fetch won't change any of your local branches, it will just give git information on what exists on the server.

Here is a related StackOverflow question that you might want to also look at when you have time: [How to rebase local branch with remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master)

Answer (score 1):

I created git alias exactly for that. Put it into your ~/.gitconfig

```
[alias]
  update = "!fn() { \
    repo=${2:-origin}; \
    if [[ $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) = \"$1\" ]]; \
    then \
        git pull \"${repo}\"; \
    else \
        git fetch \"${repo}\" \"$1\":\"$1\"; \
    fi; \
    }; fn"
```

then you can use `git update master` to update your local master without switching to it. Or, if your remote is not `origin` but, say, `upstream`, you can use `git update master upstream`. What about Intellij, seems that there is no such feature out of the box.