# Git - How to pull latest changes from a Branch that is rebased remotely

Tags: git, rebase

The problem I face is the following. I created a Branch. I made a couple of commits and then made a Pull Request.

After the code review, the reviewer made 2 comments, and rebased with the UI(Gitlab), the remote of the Branch. Now my local changes do not have the latest commits. But before I address the comments he made, I need to bring the changes to local.

What I did, and I am really not sure, it is correct, is `git fetch` and the pulled the origin of my branch, which theoretically should be the remote.

```
git fetch
git pull origin myBranch
```

Is there a better way to do that. I am struggling with this kind of situation and not sure if my approach is correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch //Fetch all remote branches.

git checkout yourBranchName //Switch branches or restore working tree files

git pull origin yourBranchName //Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch

git rebase mainBranchName yourBranchName //Reapply commits on top of another base tip

git push --force origin yourBranchName // Update remote refs along with associated objects forcefully
```

[For more details please check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master)

Comment: The `--all` flag to `git fetch` means fetch from all *remotes*. It automatically fetches all branches (modulo any settings from `--single-branch`, which `--all` does not override). Supplying `--all` to `git fetch` is usually useless-but-harmless, since most Git repositories have only one remote.

Comment: Having run `git fetch`, it's not necessary to use `git pull`: `git pull` just means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, typically `git merge`*. (You can select `git rebase` as the second command instead.) So, either use `git fetch` and then the appropriate second command, *or* use `git pull`. An extra fetch is generally harmless, but as with `--all`, it's also not generally useful.

Comment: Some people strongly prefer using `git pull`; I strongly prefer avoiding it, in favor of doing the two separate commands. That's more a style issue, though.

Comment: @torek, Thank you for your suggestions I will update my answer according to your suggestions. that's better :-)