# How to git reset all commits of a branch without losing changes?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of commits in a branch. I would like to recommit them today starting from a fresh branch rather than having my old commits. How can I do that, comparing with master? I couldn't find a similar question on SO, they all did `reset --hard`, and I don't want to lose my changes.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you talking about a rebase?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7929369/113848) do what you want to do?

Comment: I also don't understand the question -- are you looking to merely rename the branch (because you made a typo or similar)? You can rename in any Git UI tool by simply right-clicking the branch. Or from the CLI, `git branch -m <newname>`.

Comment: I want to take my old commits on branch A and put them into one commit on a new branch B, dated today.

Comment: ^ That sounds like a squash (and possibly rename) / rebase. `git rebase` or `git merge --squash`.

Comment: You don't lose any commits with `reset --hard` if you have previously added a branch to hold your current place. See my essay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard/59675191#59675191 — what you are describing appears to be regret 3 (though if you also want the squash you would also have regret 1).

Comment: You can start a fresh (in terms of history) by starting an orphan branch: `git checkout -b --orphan new-branch; git commit -m "First commit in new history"`

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, let's break it into two points.

1. Adding commits from a branch A to branch B

For this, you can use `git cherry-pick`

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick sha1^..sha2
```

will add those commits to the current branch.

2. Change time to current time.

You can do that by the commands mentioned in this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git).