# Merge failed: Rebase failed. Please rebase locally. Please try again

Tags: git, rebase

When I create a Merge Request from `Branch A` to `Branch B`, I get the following error:

```
"Merge failed: Rebase failed. Please rebase locally. Please try again."
```

I was able to create the Merge Request successfully before but I this time, I am getting that error.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in Branch A or in git in order to avoid that error.

**This is what I have tried:** 
I have made few more commits in Branch A and tried again but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: We need debugging details. Right now there's not enough information to help

Comment: On creating a Merge Request from `Branch A` to `Branch B`, I am getting the following error: `"Merge failed: Rebase failed. Please rebase locally. Please try again."`  I am wondering what I need to do in order to avoid that problem. When this error usually shows up ?

Comment: You say _"On creating a Merge Request"_ - Where is this rebase being done? What happens when you try it locally?

Comment: I didn't do any rebase. Just simply I was creating a Merge Request from `Branch A` to `Branch B` and I got that error.

Comment: _"I was creating a Merge Request"_ - how? Where? _"I didn't do any rebase"_ - the error says you are.

Comment: Is this on Gitlab? Github? Where?

Comment: This is on GitLab, not on GitHub.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was creating a Merge Request from *Branch A* to *Branch B* in GitLab.  When trying to merge, I got that error. Before, I was successfully able to create a MR from *Branch A* to *Branch B* without any problem in GitLab. I am wondering why this time, I got that error. Just wondering.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Its a new error. I never saw that error while creating a *MR*

Answer (score 0):

git pull --rebase origin BranchB

Comment: What this command do ? Does it has any effect on `Branch B`? I don't want to have any effect on `Branch B` because that is not my branch. My branch is `Branch A`. I am creating a `MR` from `Branch A` to `Branch B`

Comment: The rebase could not be done automatically, as there might be some conflicts,. You need to get the latest changes for branch B and then do a rebase on branch A.
This command will not affect branch B in any way. After this command you still need to commit and push in order to do the MR.
Here is a answer to what local rebasing is, where instead of branch B you have master.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-onto-remote-master

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).